# Can I put E10 unleaded fuel in my 2004 Ford Freestar 4.2L?

Tags: ford, fuel-system

I live in The Netherlands and have an imported Ford Freestar 4.2L from the USA. This car is unknown in Europe and I can't find any info about this car over here.

Can I put E10 (10% Ethanol) unleaded fuel in my car?

Comment: Don't worry about the English, it's pretty good! I've made a couple of minor  corrections for you

Comment: In Brazil people have to use E25 in their imports and this does not look to be a major source of problems.

Answer (score 4):

All vehicles should be able to handle E10 fuel, even older vehicles which were produced before ethanol was used in fuel. It's when you get above this (ie: E15+) where you need to worry about what you're putting into your tank. Most all the fuel sold in the States is E10, so have no fear.

Comment: Thank you for the quick respons.
I am glad to hear this. Patrick Brink
Prinsenbeek
The Netherlands

Comment: Do you have any authoritative references for these claims? I'd like to read up more on the topic. :)

Comment: As an American who also drives a car, I believe he has all the authority he needs to make that claim. Almost every single gas station and grade with the occasional notable exception for premium in some states (Wisconson is one) serves up E10.

Comment: @JoErNanO - If you trust [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_ethanol_fuel_mixtures#E10_or_less), it has information in the beginning of the article stating such. Also, look at some of the reference links at the bottom of the article. There is some corroborating information there as well.